# How to rename a container in Azure Cosmos DB with Java SQL API?

Tags: java, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, azure-java-sdk

It look like that [it is not possible to rename a container in the Azure Cosmos DB](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/19466575-add-ability-to-rename-databases-and-collections). It should be copy to the new container via a bulk operation. How can I do this with the Java SDK? Are there any samples for it?

Comment: Do the below comments help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem by linking instead copying all the data. This simulate an rename of the container. Instead of one container I use two container now. The first contains only the name of the second container.

Now I can build the new version of the container. If I are finish I change the name of the saved container name. Then I drop the old container.

The tricky is to inform all nodes of the app to use the new container name.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right. Changing container name is currently not possible. As I understand, you want to discard old container (as you wanted to rename initially) and migrate data to new one.

**Data Migration tool is a great tool to do so: [Tutorial: Use Data migration tool to migrate your data to Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data)**

Also, do check out [Bulk Executor library for Java](https://search.maven.org/search?q=documentdb-bulkexecutor), [API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.bulkexecutor?view=azure-java-stable) and [samples](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-bulkexecutor-java-getting-started).

You can use `importAll` in [BulkExecutor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.bulkexecutor.documentbulkexecutor?view=azure-java-stable) class:

```
ConnectionPolicy connectionPolicy = new ConnectionPolicy();
 RetryOptions retryOptions = new RetryOptions();
 
 // Set client's retry options high for initialization
 retryOptions.setMaxRetryWaitTimeInSeconds(120);
 retryOptions.setMaxRetryAttemptsOnThrottledRequests(100);
 connectionPolicy.setRetryOptions(retryOptions);
 connectionPolicy.setMaxPoolSize(1000);

 DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient(HOST, MASTER_KEY, connectionPolicy, null);

 String collectionLink = String.format("/dbs/%s/colls/%s", "mydb", "mycol");
 DocumentCollection collection = client.readCollection(collectionLink, null).getResource();

 DocumentBulkExecutor executor = DocumentBulkExecutor.builder().from(client, collection,
     collection.getPartitionKey(), collectionOfferThroughput).build();

 // Set retries to 0 to pass control to bulk executor
 client.getConnectionPolicy().getRetryOptions().setMaxRetryWaitTimeInSeconds(0);
 client.getConnectionPolicy().getRetryOptions().setMaxRetryAttemptsOnThrottledRequests(0);
 
 for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   List documents = documentSource.getMoreDocuments();

   BulkImportResponse bulkImportResponse = executor.importAll(documents, false, true, 40);

   // Validate that all documents inserted to ensure no failure.
   if (bulkImportResponse.getNumberOfDocumentsImported() < documents.size()) {
      for(Exception e: bulkImportResponse.getErrors()) {
          // Validate why there were some failures.
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
      break;
   }
 }

 executor.close();
 client.close();
```

Comment: My understand is that this is a GUI tool. I need a Java API for it.

Comment: Sure, check out Bulk Executor library for Java: https://search.maven.org/search?q=documentdb-bulkexecutor, API documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.bulkexecutor?view=azure-java-stable and samples: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-bulkexecutor-java-getting-started

Comment: Let me know if this helps.

Comment: That doesn't really help. It points only to a library which contains again hundreds of settings.

Comment: But I guess your initial question was about supportability in Java SDK and samples. hence, shared.

Comment: Your samples are only for bulkdelete, bulkimport and bulkupdate. What I had needed is a sample for bulkcopy with the parameters of the source collection and target collection. The main difference is that the data are already in the database. I does not want transfer all the data to the client and back to the database. For such a transfer I does not need an extra library. In the sample I can not see such inner database transfer.
Another problem is that the sample start from a command line. I have an com.azure.cosmos.CosmosContainer object and need a rename. This means all details must copy.

Comment: Okay. Thnx for the clarification.